# How to download android lollipop source code for Nexus 9?

Tags: android, github, linux-kernel, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to download android lollipop source code for Nexus 9. I used below mentioned    repository to download and sync for nexus.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.0.0_r1
repo sync
```

But after syncing 96% I am getting error as below mentioned logs:

```
Fetching projects:  97% (468/482)  Fetching project platform/external/freetype
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found    
Fetching project platform/hardware/intel/common/bd_prov
Fetching project platform/external/chromium_org/v8    
Fetching project platform/external/tagsoup    
Fetching project platform/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/host/headers    
Fetching projects:  98% (473/482)  Fetching project platform/packages/apps/Dialer    
Fetching project platform/external/libunwind    
Fetching project platform/packages/apps/Protips    
Fetching project platform/packages/apps/Calculator    
Fetching project platform/external/jsmn   
Fetching projects:  99% (478/482)  Fetching project platform/external/compiler-rt    
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found    
error: Cannot fetch platform/packages/apps/OMA-DM
error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

**Note:**
When I tried to check `ssh connectivity` its showing `Permission denied public key` as below:

```
$ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.131' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have one question. After the source code downloaded, do you compile it for Nexus 9 and flash the image onto it ? Is it successful?

Comment: For the ssh issue (which seems unrelated to the failure to sync OMA-DM) you should follow [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing about ssh connectivity since you can sync about 96%.

Occasionally, it might exit sync due to network errors. You can try repo sync again, and see whether the project can be fetched. I ever meet the case same as yours, and resync will be ok.

Or use:

```
$ repo sync -f
```

The -f flag will ignore the network errors or unfeteched projects, and continue syncing. After it's done, execute repo sync again to be sure that all projects are synced successfully.